# How to send 300 mails every 1 minute with PHPMailer

Tags: php, mysql, email, queue, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer. How to send 300 mails every minute? I have a total of 13000 mails.
Maybe I can use mysql like this:

```
$start =$_POST['start'];
$sql=mysql_query("select id,email,fname,lname from users where email !='' and group_id=2  limit $start, 300");

$start =1 
$start = 301
.
.
.
.
echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=sendmail.php?start=$start'>";
```

Other example

```
<?php

set_time_limit(20);

while ($i<=10)
{
        echo "i=$i ";
        sleep(100);
        $i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: The problem is the 300 emails/minute or the 1-minute interval?

Comment: can you ssh into your server at all? or just (s)ftp?

Comment: I want mail queue to send 300 mails every 1 minute because of server load balance. Get rid of performance lack of server for sending mail.

Comment: @Rick Burgess, i dont have ssh into server, only web site.

Answer (score 0):

a cron job is all you need. Do you have access to the crontab of your server?

Comment: I have no access to the crontab of server

Comment: Sounds like you need a better server.

Answer (score 0):

Just run PHP script from Command Line Interface:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

while(true) { 

   // magic, send 300 mails, do some heavy job, whatever

   sleep(60);

}
```